# Javascript - convert CEST date to local user date

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

My server returns date in CEST time zone. Is there any way to convert that date to local user date? Something like

```
var CEST_date = new Date( some_CEST_timestamp );
var local_time = //some code that converts CEST_date to local user date.
```

I've found Moment.js library but I cannot find timezone to different timezone conversion in the docs.

Comment: Is there a way you could get the server to return a UTC time. That's much easier to convert to local time.

Comment: Moment.js has an extra library for timezones, maybe you can use that? or maybe you checked that too.

https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: What is the value of *some_CEST_timestamp*? Does it include the actual timezone offset? There are many good parsers and formatters available (e.g. [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) and [*Moment.js*](http://momentjs.com)), or if you only have to deal with one format a simple function can be about 4 lines.

Comment: CEST is in seconds, I already figured out how to convert timezone using moment.js